# Android: Launch application and take screen shot

Tags: java, android, eclipse, screenshot

It is possible, that my application launches when a certain app (app-xyz) starts. and take screen shot on every click in app-xyz.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  This is for security-  if you could do this, you could take screenshots of people entering passwords.  The only way to take a screenshot if you aren't the active activity is to use adb or similar tool.

Comment: Thanks Gabe for your response.